# How to open an android Activity by clicking a link in sms

Tags: android, service

I am trying to open my android app activity by clicking a link which is received in a sms her is my activity code to open.In this application i am working with Http services.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        user = bundle.getString("Username");
        pass = bundle.getString("Password");

        //initializing listview and hero list
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        tktList = new ArrayList<>();
        //this method will fetch and parse the data
        loadHeroList();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:

                SharedPreferences SM = getSharedPreferences("userrecord", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = SM.edit();
                edit.putBoolean("username", false);
                edit.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.user:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void loadHeroList() {
        //getting the progressbar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //making the progressbar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //creating a string request to send request to the url
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://182.18.163.39/list_details.php?username="+user+"&key="+pass,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hiding the progressbar after completion
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = jsonobject.getString("Sno");
                                String Tktid = jsonobject.getString("TKTID");
                                link = jsonobject.getString("Link");

                                List list = new List(user, pass, jsonobject.getString("Sno"), jsonobject.getString("TKTID"),jsonobject.getString("Link"));
                                tktList.add(list);

                                Log.i("website content", name);
                                Log.i("website content", Tktid);
                                Log.i("website content", link);

                            }

                            //creating custom adapter object
                            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(tktList, getApplicationContext());
                            //adding the adapter to listview
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //creating a request queue
        com.android.volley.RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //adding the string request to request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

here what i want to get is when i send link through SMS and by clicking that  link it will open the particular activity file Can anyone help me to complete this.

Comment: Go through - https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html. Just as a side point, that was just a google search away.

Comment: used firebase deep link concept.

Comment: actually i am new to android can you please help me  to use deep links

Answer (score 0):

You can read chrome browser link, Just add some code in your manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```